# Значение скрипта на jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет!

кому не сложно,можете объяснить подробно выполнение этого скрипта(простая галерея картинок)?

```
$(function(){

    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();

    setInterval(function(){        
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(1000).next('img').fadeIn(1000)
                                 .end().appendTo('.fadein');
    } ,3000);

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();` - в элементе с классом `.fadein`, скрыть картинку, начиная с самой первой (индекс ноль)

функция таймера с шагом в 3000 миллисекунд, которая поочередно скрывает и показывает img, начиная с самой первой дочерней от `fadein` со скоростью 1000 миллисекунд. По достижении конца данного интервала цикл заканчивается.

Но больно как-то замысловато написано. Видно, что либо костыль, либо узкоспециализированная штука.

Comment: не сочти за трудность,а можешь написать облегченную версию?

Comment: $(function(){

$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
$(".fadein img").fadeToggle(1000);
});

Comment: не работает